# Separate Collision Bounds

Tags: game-engine, collision

How would I add a separate collision bound for a character in Blender Game? I want to be able to detect collisions on different areas of the body and have different amounts of damage done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure if what you are saying is possible. Someone else would have to comment on that.

**However**, I do know what I would do to fix it.

1. **Create** a new object for each section you would like. *(Tip: perhapse you could use empties to avoid step 4)*
2. **Parent** your new collision objects to the main object for which you are tracking collision.
3. Set up the **scripts** so that when one of these objects is hit, it sends a message to the parent object.
4. Set these collision objects to **not** be rendered and **not affect physics** simulations (gravity, collision, etc.)

I hope this method helps.

Thanks, Uncle Snail